# Problem with extending DxiColumn in DevExtreme DataGrid

Tags: angular, typescript, devexpress, devextreme

First of all, I am aware that extending Angular Devextreme components are not officially supported. However, I have managed to successfully extend DataGrid and DxoLookup components and added the desired functionalities to them, but when it comes to DxiColumn I have faced some problems and I will be glad if anyone give me some guidance.

Here is a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ykmgm)

This is how I extend **DxiColumn**.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NestedOptionHost } from 'devextreme-angular/core';
import { DxiColumnComponent } from 'devextreme-angular/ui/nested';

@Component({
  selector: 'dxi-number-column',
  template: '',
})
export class AppNumberColumnComponent extends DxiColumnComponent {
  constructor(parentOptionHost: NestedOptionHost, optionHost: NestedOptionHost) {
    super(parentOptionHost, optionHost);
  }
}
```

```
// app.module.ts
 declarations: [
    AppNumberColumnComponent,
   ....
  ],
imports: [
    DxDataGridModule,
    DxiColumnModule,
    ...
  ],
```

However, once I try to use the column in a DataGrid, Typescript will complain that properties are not members of this component, although the app will compile, the column is not rendered in the grid.

```
<dxi-number-column
     dataField="qty"
     dataType="number"
     [calculateCellValue]="qtyCellValueExpr"
   >
</dxi-number-column>
```

```
Can't bind to 'calculateCellValue' since it isn't a known property of 'dxi-number-column'.
1. If 'dxi-number-column' is an Angular component and it has 'calculateCellValue' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'dxi-number-column' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

**"devextreme": "20.1.7",
"devextreme-angular": "20.1.7",**